# UAE visa question

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, uae

I hold an Indian passport and traveling from Sofia to India.
Which visa should I apply for Dubai with a 7 hour layover (Exactly 6 hour 55 minutes) in Dubai? I am reaching DWC airport from SOF airport at 20:10 hours on 2nd October, next flight is from DXB airport to BLR airport at 03:05 hours on 3rd October.
96 hours transit visas require at least 8 hours of transit time and I have 6 hours 55 minutes transit time.
Is there a chance to get 96 hours transit visa ?

Comment: I don't think you can get 96 hour transit visas on arrival at DWC. Timatic doesn't say you can, so you'll likely be denied boarding at Sofia, unless you get a visa in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As your itinerary falls just short the requirements, the 96-hour visa on arrival does not appear to be an option. Additionally, your arrival and departure are at two separate airports.

Should you be flying either [Etihad](https://www.etihad.com/en-us/before-you-fly/visas/) or [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/prearranged-uae-visas.aspx), you can apply on the web site of either airline. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates) also lists Air Arabia, Air Astana, Air Baltic, Air Serbia, flydubai, Turkish Airlines, and Indigo Airlines as airlines through which UAE visas can be arranged, but you should check and confirm with your carrier.

Otherwise, you would need to [make arrangements for a visa](https://www.government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae#visa-on-arrival) prior to your journey.